# Ignore comma within nested parentheses for a Regex match

Tags: regex

I have the following Regex `/[^,\s]+(?:\s+\([^)]*\))?/g` that allows me to match elements separated by a comma while ignoring the commas inside `()`

Having this:

```
a,b,c (aaa, bbb, ccc),d
```

I get this

```
a
b
c (aaa, bbb, ccc)
d
```

Now, I want to upgrade it to consider another level of parentheses. I don't want to consider **any level** (I know recursive is not possible) but only 2 level max.

Having this:

```
a,(b, b),c (aaa, (bbb, cccc, ddd)),d
```

I need to get

```
a
(b, b)
c (aaa, (bbb, cccc, ddd))
d
```

---

I am using https://regex101.com/ for testing if that helps.

Comment: Try `(?:\([^()]*(?:\([^()]*\)[^()]*)*\)|[^,])+`. See https://regex101.com/r/zJtxNM/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew seems to work fine :) but how to make it works inside the match() of Javascript? I am not getting the same result there :s

Comment: Doesn't `text.match(/(?:\([^()]*(?:\([^()]*\)[^()]*)*\)|[^,])+/g)` work?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes yes, nevermind. Forgot the `g` at the end -.-. You can make it an answer if you want :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```js
const matches = text.match(/(?:\([^()]*(?:\([^()]*\)[^()]*)*\)|[^,])+/g);
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zJtxNM/1).

The regex matches one or more repetitions of

- `\([^()]*(?:\([^()]*\)[^()]*)*\)` - a `(` + zero or more chars other than parentheses + zero or more repetitions of a substring between parentheses followed with zero or more chars other than parentheses + a `)` char (substring between max two-level nested parentheses)
- `|` - or
- `[^,]` - a char other than a comma.